# WPF: How to achieve an automatic full screen that not hides the taskbar, with no resize and no window style?

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen

How to achieve an automatic full screen that not hides the taskbar, with no resize and no window style?

I tried to use the following code, but it doesn't work right, as shown in the image below.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Test_Environment.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="50">Top</Button>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="50">Bottom</Button>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="50">Left</Button>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50">Right</Button>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50">Center</Button>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
        MinHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
        MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
        MinWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
    }
}
```

Here is the result:
[image: Result]

As you can see, the "Bottom" button is partially underneath the taskbar, and I want it to be entirely above it. So, ideally, it would look as shown in the following image, but without the border on the top:
[image]

Comment: calculate height of Taskbar and set the height of window = (Scree Height - TaskBar height)

Comment: Why not use just the [WindownState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx)?. Maximized state should do all the work for you.

Comment: @icebat - Because I don't want the "x" button on the top...

Comment: @null1941- Thanks, I will try it. But isn't there any solution that is more... elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with calls to unmanaged code. Check [this](https://codekong.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/custom-window-style-and-accounting-for-the-taskbar/) article to see how to do it. Basically, just remove your width and height settings from code-behind, implement the `WindowSizing` class from the article and call it from `SourceInitialized` event of the window.

**Edit**

The other solution would be to add reference to Windows Forms and use:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the width and height values to the values of working area
    this.Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    this.Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    // Move the window to top left corner of the screen
    this.Left = 0;
    this.Top = 0;   
}
```

Just make sure to remove `WindowState="Maximized"` from your window.

Not sure if any of these is elegant though.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you need to dock it to the top left?

Comment: Because window is not maximized, it just has the width and height of working area, which is the area of the screen without the taskbar. So if you were to position it anywhere else, it would go out of the working area bounds or over the taskbar.