# How to remove title bar of a window when it's maximized and keep the taskbar visible in the meantime?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, taskbar, titlebar

As the title says. I want to be able to hide the title bar of the MainWindow when it's maximized but I want to to keep the taskbar visible. It should work for multiple monitors. Only WPF.

Comment: Have you tried to set [`WindowStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)? How "multiple monitors" make it different (we don't know, you tell us)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35796689/780089) answer. The first solution should work on multiple monitors.